# Going Down Theorem, AM

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand the proof of the going down theorem in *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and Macdonald. My main confusion is when they say it suffices to show that $B_{\mathfrak q_1}\mathfrak p_2\cap A = \mathfrak p_2$. Isn't it true that $x\in B_{\mathfrak q_1}\mathfrak p_2\cap A$ iff $x \in A$ and $x/1 \in B_{\mathfrak q_1}\mathfrak p_2$? I don't understand this notation.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in the notation? If you don't understand it, you might want to trace back and read the definitions.

Comment: When we say that (B_1)2 intersect A = 2, do we mean that the contraction of (B_1)2 into B (under the standard map from B to B_1, given by f(x)=x/1), contracted again under the inclusion mapping into A, then intersected with A, is equal to 2?

Comment: Bunch of symbols missing there.

Comment: Well, if we write it carefully, $x \in \mathfrak{p}_2 B_{\mathfrak{q}_1} \cap A$ means that $x$ can be written as $b/s$ with $b \in \mathfrak{p}_2$ and $x$ can also be written as $c/1$, with $c \in A$. Note that the way to write a quotient is not uniquely determined.

Could you write properly what's the relation between $\mathfrak{q}_1$ and $\mathfrak{p}_2$?

Comment: That makes sense. And for the going down theorem, we are given A $\subset$ B, A is integrally closed (in its field of fractions), B is integral over A, and given $p_1$ $\supset$ $p_2$, both prime ideals in A, and $q_1$ prime in B st $q_1 \cap A = p_1$ and we want to show there exists some $q_2 \in B$, prime, st $q_1 \supset q_2$ and $q_2 \cap A = p_2$